# PHP converting unknown datetime string to datetime object

Tags: php, datetime, type-conversion, iso8601

I am having trouble with the following string which is supposed to be a datetime (response from an api).

> 2013-03-08T19:11:11.234+0000

I need to convert the string to ISO 8601.
The exact format should look like:

> 2016-03-01T12:00:00+00:00

If someone could help me do this in php would be great but I would be already more than happy if someone could identify the format (like `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the API returns the time with milliseconds.

Try this:

```
$date = '2013-03-08T19:11:11.234+0000';
$format = 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s.uO';

$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);
echo $dt->format(DateTime::ISO8601);
```

Result:

```
2013-03-08T19:11:11+0000
```

**EDIT**

Based on comments on your answer, you need to convert such a time:

```
2016-03-01T11:01:51.126044 00:00
```

Since it's not possible to parse this format with DateTime, you need to make it readable first.

There are many ways to do this. What we need is to add a `+` before timezone, so that my code above work.

If you are sure the date you get from the API is **always** this format, and that there will **always** be only 1 space in the string, just replace the string with a space:

```
$date = '2016-03-01T11:01:51.126044 00:00';
str_replace(' ', '+', $date);

$format = 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s.uP';

$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);
echo $dt->format(DateTime::ISO8601);
```

This should work (note that here the timezone mask is `P` since there is a colon)

You can also use `preg_replace()` instead of DateTime, if you don't need the date for calculations:

```
$date = '2016-03-01T11:01:51.126044 00:00';
$date = preg_replace('`(\.[0-9]+\s)`', '+', $date);
echo $date;
```

This produces:

```
2016-03-01T11:01:51+00:00
```

If you need the date for calculation, just convert it to DateTime after:

```
$date = '2016-03-01T11:01:51.126044 00:00';
$date = preg_replace('`(\.[0-9]+\s)`', '+', $date);
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat(DateTime::ISO8601, $date);
var_dump($date);
```

This produces:

```
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2016-03-01 11:01:51.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(1)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(6) "+00:00"
}
```

Comment: Thanks you so much Arcesilas. you can't imagine how helpful that was.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use Carbon: http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

```
echo Carbon::parse('2013-03-08T19:11:11.234+0000')->toAtomString();
```

Also, the format you want is ATOM, not ISO 8601. You could do @Arcesilas way, it should work too.

Comment: Carbon is very nice, but I think a little to heavy in this case.

By the way, with Carbon, you can use `format(DateTime::ISO8601)` too

Comment: i tried but ended up with: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string ($var) at position 0 ($): Unexpected character' in /var/www/html/carbon.php:237 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/carbon.php(237): DateTime->__construct('$var', Object(DateTimeZone)) #1 /var/www/html/carbon.php(270): Carbon\Carbon->__construct('$var', NULL) #2 /var/www/html/scopearea.php(118): Carbon\Carbon::parse('$var') #3 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/carbon.php on line 237 ..
thanks though